# Open activity as pop-up and not in other screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, popup

I am working with Bluetooth Chat sample code. In sample app the Device opens up in another screen but I have implemented the same code with the difference that `DeviceListActivity` is called as soon as the app is started but this opens it in another screen and I want that it should be opened as pop-up in Bluetooth chat sample code.

Can someone let me know how to open Activity as pop-up?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

in your manifest file, set your activity theme to dialog

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Actually, I just forgot to look into the manifest file of Bluetooth Chat sample.

Comment: My App crashes when I do this.